# "improve tag wiki" should be greyed out like "edit" while banned from editing

Tags: feature-request, edits, user-interface, tag-wiki, edit-ban

I made a series of edit suggestions on meta over the past week to add a new tag, which were rejected. As a result, I'm banned from editing for the next 7 days. No complaints there.

I just clicked an "improve tag wiki" link, and was served with this page:

> ```
> Too many of your edits were rejected, try again in 7 days.
> ```

Note that that's the *source* of the page - it's a plaintext response.

This isn't how the "edit" links on posts behave - they're greyed out for me, with the title text:

> Account is not allowed to suggest edits

I propose:

1. "improve tag wiki" links should be greyed out, like edit links
2. Both types of disabled edit links should have the title text *"Too many of your edits were rejected, try again in 7 days"*

Comment: I'm also suspicious that that page will continue to say "try again in 7 days" for the next 6 days, then will suddenly be alright. Or worse, I'll come back to it in 5 days, and see ["try again in 1 days"](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105)

Comment: @animuson: Why was my meta tag incorrect? I've been experiencing this problem on meta, not the main site

Comment: You can't be edit-banned on the main site, though, so obviously you wouldn't experience it there. But this problem is likely related to *all* sites and not just Meta.

Comment: @animuson: Fair enough. _I_ can't or _one_ can't?

Comment: You, specifically, can't, because you have over 20,000 reputation there and can freely edit tag wikis without approval.

Answer (score 1):

Showing the "improve tag info" button when a user is edit banned is pretty confusing.

What's even more confusing however is the [message users see](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251550/351462) when they try to suggest edits to tag info.

[image: "This post has been deleted - no more edits are allowed"]

At the very least, it should use the same message for when you try to edit a question or answer while edit banned.

> You are temporarily banned from suggesting edits - please review [your edit history](https://superuser.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=suggestions).